# Keep lines below cursor in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I use Notepad++ to edit transcripts and I'd like to keep the text cursor in the center of my screen instead of it reaching the last line at the bottom of notepad++ and me having to scroll down to show more lines again. Is there a setting in Notepad++ for this or a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the viewport by shifting few lines up or down without moving your text cursor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

(Or just reach your mouse wheel and scroll it.)